# Results vary with size of dataset in classification

Tags: machine-learning

I am classifying data using a trained model and the results vary with size. e.g. suppose I have n rows initially and classify them and get a set of results X. Now if I add m rows to the previous dataset and have n+m rows and classify it then the results are different for first n rows also. And yes the change is not negligible. Please if anyone can provide an insight into this. Please let me know if the question is not clear. I am using R and the classifier is SVM.

Comment: You'd have to provide some more info. At least: what language are you using? What  classifier are you using?

Comment: I am using R and the classifier I used is SVM

Comment: and thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly the reason would be because an SVM model is a representation of all your sample as points in space.

Just from Wikipedia:

> That means all your data is mapped so that the examples of the
>   separate categories are divided by a clear gap that is as wide as
>   possible.

All your examples are mapped into that same space and predicted to belong to a category based on which side of the gap they fall on.

Since all the data is mapped, a new dataset could mean a new division, affecting your final result.

Comment: Ohh...yes, It's clear now. But I have millions of rows in my testing dataset and I have divided it into chunks. Will the type of text I have in a chunk affect final results noticeably?

Comment: I'd say not too significantly, but to be on the safe side you can randomly split the dataset a few times and compare results.

Comment: Yes, I tried splitting the dataset randomly and as you said the difference is not too significant. Thanks